# Expect script output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, expect

I am trying to output the size of an ARP table from a FW using an Expect script so it can be graphed. After the below code the output displayed to screen is shown:

```
/usr/bin/expect -f -<< EOD
spawn ssh test@1.2.3.4
sleep 1
expect {
"*word:" {send "password\r"}
}
sleep 1
expect {
"*>" {send "show arp all | match \"total ARP entries in table\"\r"}
}
sleep 1
expect {
"*>" {send "exit\r"} 
}
expect eof
EOD

spawn ssh test@1.2.3.4
FW-Active
Password:
Number of failed attempts since last successful login: 0
test@FW-Active(active)> show arp all | match "total ARP entries in table"
total ARP entries in table :        2861
```

What I am trying to do is be able to output only the numeric value indicated from the total ARP entries in table. I am assuming I need to some how do a "cut" or "awk" or something to extract only the numbers but I am not having any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You store the output of that whole command in a variable, let's say `a`.
Something like this will probably work. Since you're using expect, you might want to figure out how to store that output as a variable that way you can manipulate it. I stored the output as $a in my example.

```
$ echo $a
total ARP entries in table : 2861
$ echo ${a% *}
total ARP entries in table :
$ echo ${a% *}-
total ARP entries in table : -
$ echo ${a##* }
2861
```

**Logic explanation (Parameter/Variable Substituion in BASH)**:
1) To removing/stripping the left hand side part, use `#` for reaching the first matching character value (reading / parsing from left side), `##` for reaching the last matching character/value. It works by giving `*<value>` within the `{` `}` braces.

2) To removing/stripping the right hand side part, use `%` for reaching the first matching character value (reading / parsing from right side), `%%` for reaching the last matching character/value. It works by giving `<value>*` within the `{` `}` braces.

Or if you don't want to store the output or anything, then simply do this:

```
show arp all | match "total ARP entries in table" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*"
```

Or (the following assumes that you don't change

```
show arp all | match "total ARP entries in table" | sed "s/  *//g"|cut -d':' -f2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I will research how to use variable in expect. Unfortunately the Firewall doesn't allow the further use of RegEX, such as you proposed by using grep and sed. I will maybe try logging output to file and then extract the numbers from there. Thanks.